# It's posible call vb.net codebehind method from ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I try to call a codebehind function from ajax jquery function on aspx, but I recibed the messagge **500 (Internal Server Error.)**
If i check the web developer tools on IE, i found the messagge **No se puede encontrar el tipo 'Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter'**

this is my Js function on visorMapa.aspx

```
function getMarkersMap(indicador) {
        getFiltros()
        console.log("indicador: " + indicador + ", flota: " + flota + ", t.Unidad: " + tUni + ",marca: " + marca)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'visorMapa.aspx/getMarkers',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log("good Job");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("something is wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
```

this is the function on codebehind

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getMarkers() As String
    Return "It's Ok"
End Function
```

I read about uncommet some lines about jsonSerialization on web.config and the lines are uncomment in my web.config.
I want to know if is possible call web method on codebehind from ajax.
I thinking on make a web services, or Partial class, I never make a partial class but i want to know if is an option. 
I'm open to another options.

what I need is get json object with data from db from vb.net and handle on javascript.
I'm use vb.net 2008
Today make new testers. 
I made a WS example on a new vb.net solution and call the default WS function (hello world) from Js and works fine. Then I do the same on my vb solution and doesn't work. The problem is not the Js function or WS. Also test the WS on the browser and works. 
 I think that maybe is the web.config or something else. What other test can i do?

Comment: Can you translate your error ?

Comment: using asmx (web service ) is one of the preferred way ; other than that like previous comment can you translate the error

Comment: The error say: **Doesn't find the type 'Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter'** @Mairaj Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

Go to "RouteConfig.vb" under "App_Start" folder.

Change following line

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
```

To

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off
```

Please refer: http://forums.asp.net/t/1975897.aspx?jquery+ajax+calls+to+asp+net+web+methods+authentication+error+

Comment: Hi, I do that, and I have the same result. I thing the problem is somthing of configuration or headers on the Js call, because I make a new WS in a new solution and call it with the same function and works fine. But if I try to do the same in my solution doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, I found that it was not any problem with jquery call.
I implemented your code and made it work.
I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share an optional solution that i found. I think that the problem is the application group in the IIS. I use **Classic .Net AppPool Version Net CLR: 2.0** for this specific project. 
The solution that I found it was don't use WS and use an AJAX library.
1.- Add AJAX object on load Event vb.net (visorMapa_VisorMapa is the name of my partial class defined by vb.net)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
             Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(GetType(visorMapa_VisorMapa))
             'more code on load page event...
End Sub
```

2.- Adding this line on top of my vb.net function

```
 <Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)> _
Public Function getMarkerMap(ByVal accion As Integer, Optional ByVal flota As Integer = -1) As String
'some code here and return JSON....
 result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
 Return result
End Function
```

3.- And call it from Js like this

```
//JS Function
function getMarkersMap(indicador) {
    getFiltros();
    visorMapa_VisorMapa.getMarkerMap(indicador, flota, getMarkers_CallBack);
}
//the callback
function getMarkers_CallBack(data) {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = JSON.parse(data.value);
    //console.log(markers[0].poslat);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var mylatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].poslat, markers[i].poslon);
        console.log(markers[i].poslat + ", " + markers[i].poslon);
    }
```

On this way I can call codebehind Function from JavaScript and get JSON object that I can handle it on Js.
I appreciate your help. And maybe this is not the best solution but in that case, it works.